# Combined barplot modify x-axis tick labels in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am having an issue with the order my x-axis tick labels are appearing. I have created a graph with combined data. In the x-axis I have labeled the samples used, but for the first three datasets (six, eight, twelve weeks) two samples were used for each bar column. In the last set (terminal point) the AbxFMT_2901 should correspond to the AbxFMT_2901/2902 of the the three previous datasets because at the terminal point I only had one sample (2901) and lost the other (2902). That label should only appear at the terminal point portion and it should be the first in order.[image]

This is the code I have used to generate the graph:

```
df = bind_rows(six_wks_huCD45_AbxFMT, eight_wks_huCD45_AbxFMT, twelve_wks_huCD45_AbxFMT, terminal_data_huCD45_PBL_AbxFMT)

df$orderweeks = factor(df$weeks, levels = c('six weeks', 'eight weeks', 'twelve weeks', 'terminal point'))
df$Sample. <- as.character(df$Sample.)
df$ordersample <- factor(df$Sample., levels = unique(df$Sample.))

df_plot <- ggplot(df, aes(x = df$ordersample, y =df$`huCD45 Cell count`, group = weeks, fill = weeks))+ geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat = "identity") + facet_grid(.~orderweeks) 

df_plot + labs(x = "Samples", y= "huCD45 cell count", title = "PBL Analysis of Abx+FMT Treatment") + scale_fill_discrete(breaks = c("six weeks", "eight weeks", "twelve weeks", "terminal point")) + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))
```

And this is a sample of the dataframe:

```
Sample. huCD45 Cell count          weeks     orderweeks      ordersample
1  AbxFMT_2901/2902             860.0      six weeks      six weeks AbxFMT_2901/2902
2  AbxFMT_2903/2904            3736.0      six weeks      six weeks AbxFMT_2903/2904
3  AbxFMT_2905/2906            7137.0      six weeks      six weeks AbxFMT_2905/2906
4  AbxFMT_2907/2908            2183.0      six weeks      six weeks AbxFMT_2907/2908
5  AbxFMT_2909/2910            7485.0      six weeks      six weeks AbxFMT_2909/2910
6  AbxFMT_2911/2912            3509.0      six weeks      six weeks AbxFMT_2911/2912
7  AbxFMT_2901/2902           28296.0    eight weeks    eight weeks AbxFMT_2901/2902
8  AbxFMT_2903/2904           18084.0    eight weeks    eight weeks AbxFMT_2903/2904
9  AbxFMT_2905/2906           27602.0    eight weeks    eight weeks AbxFMT_2905/2906
10 AbxFMT_2907/2908           16706.0    eight weeks    eight weeks AbxFMT_2907/2908
11 AbxFMT_2909/2910           22571.0    eight weeks    eight weeks AbxFMT_2909/2910
12 AbxFMT_2911/2912           18731.0    eight weeks    eight weeks AbxFMT_2911/2912
13 AbxFMT_2901/2902           39975.0   twelve weeks   twelve weeks AbxFMT_2901/2902
14 AbxFMT_2903/2904           19042.0   twelve weeks   twelve weeks AbxFMT_2903/2904
15 AbxFMT_2905/2906           68493.0   twelve weeks   twelve weeks AbxFMT_2905/2906
16 AbxFMT_2907/2908           23533.0   twelve weeks   twelve weeks AbxFMT_2907/2908
17 AbxFMT_2909/2910           50678.0   twelve weeks   twelve weeks AbxFMT_2909/2910
18 AbxFMT_2911/2912           43465.0   twelve weeks   twelve weeks AbxFMT_2911/2912
19      AbxFMT_2901            1318.0 terminal point terminal point      AbxFMT_2901
20 AbxFMT_2903/2904            4565.5 terminal point terminal point AbxFMT_2903/2904
```

I have tried various ways using scale_x_discrete and continuous but it's not working. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thank you!!

Comment: Can you post the code you are running and sample data? Please edit the question with code, including calls to `library()`, and the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`. (`df` is the name of your dataset.)

Comment: Sure, just did!

Comment: One thing you need to change is: `facet_grid(.~orderweeks, scales = 'free_x')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change two things:

```
df$ordersample <- factor(df$Sample., levels = sort(unique(df$Sample.)))
```

and

```
+ facet_grid(.~orderweeks, scales = 'free_x')
```